# How to upload multiple images from front-end using JavaScript, jQuery, Ajax in JSP file and send it into Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot web application, where I want to upload multiple images of a product at a time along with other fields (for example product name, SKU code, category, tags, subcategory, etc). I have written code for RESTful API to upload multiple images and it is working perfectly for me. I tested API using postman and it is working fine. But, I don't know how to do it from the front end. I am showing you my front-end code below, where I am sending a single image to my controller using Ajax.

```
    $("#file").change(function(){
            var formData = new FormData();
              var fileSelect = document.getElementById("file");
              if(fileSelect.files && fileSelect.files.length == 1) {
                  var file = fileSelect.files[0];
                  formData.set("file",file,file.name);
                  }else{
                      $("#file").focus();
                      return false;
                  }
              var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
              try {
                    request.onreadystatechange=function() {
                        if(request.readyState==4) {
                            var v = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                            if(v.status==="OK") {
                                alert("Product Image Uploaded Successfully")
                                document.getElementById('imagepath').value = v.response;
                              }
                          }
                    }
                      request.open('POST',"<%=AkApiUrl.testuploadfile%>");
                      request.send(formData);
                  } catch(e) {
                      swal("Unable to connect to server","","error");
                  }
          });
```

As I told you, the above code is to send a single file at a time. I am showing you my API controller code also:

```
@RequestMapping(value = AkApiUrl.testuploadfile, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }) public ResponseEntity<?> testuploadfile(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
        CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
        String imgurl = "NA";
        try {
            String path = Constants.webmedia;
            String relativepath = "public/media/";
            System.out.println("Here is the image: ");
            List<MultipartFile> multifile = Arrays.asList(files);
            if( null != multifile && multifile.size()>0) {
                for (int i=0; i < multifile.size(); i++) {
                    String filename = files[i].getOriginalFilename();
                    String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."), filename.length());
                    int r = (int )(Math.random() * 500 + 1);
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    String formatdate = format.format(date);
                    formatdate = "ECOM" + formatdate + r;
                    byte[] bytes = files[i].getBytes();
                    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator + formatdate + extension)));
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    stream.flush();
                    stream.close();
                    String newimgurl = relativepath + formatdate + extension;
                    imgurl = imgurl+"##"+newimgurl;
                    if(imgurl != null) {
                        CustomResponse.setResponse(imgurl);
                        CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
                        CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
            CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
                CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
                CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
            }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

This API is working fine, I am getting desired response. But I do not know how should I implement this thing on the JSP page. Please, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is good document for same topic https://medium.com/typecode/a-strategy-for-handling-multiple-file-uploads-using-javascript-eb00a77e15f

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope it would work for me too.

Comment: I tried this way, but it did not work for me. Do you have another way?